# Function adding objects to a class through a list - calling objects

Tags: python

So I m new to this and I ve been trying to follow the DRY principle.

So I have a class

```
class Player(object):
    lifecondition = True
    hitpoints = 100
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def death(self):
        self.lifecondition = False
```

a list

```
playerlist = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player4", "Player5", 
"Player6", "Player7", "Player8", "Player9", "Player10"]
```

and a function

```
def addplayers(alist):
    for item in alist:
        item = Player("%s" % item)
        print "%s has %s HP of life and feels pretty much alive" %  (item.name, item.hitpoints, )
```

I m adding objects to the class through the function

```
addplayers(playerlist)
```

all good so far but if I do a 
    print Player1.name 
I receive that Player1 is not defined. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't have a variable called `Player1`.

Comment: Your indenting is not correct on your Player class. Is this really what you have or is it just formatted wrong in the post?

Comment: sure , but the function has iterated through my list and added objects to the class. So I want to recall those objects back. print Player1.name shouldn't be calling that object back? @newspire my post format is incorrect

Comment: You didn't save the item into (possibly) another list. (And use that list later.)

Comment: Instead of `"%s" % item`, just use `item` if it's already a string, else `str(item)`.

Comment: You have other problems too. You have declared lifecondition and hitpoints to be class variables and not instance variables. They should be declared in __init__ like you did name if you want each instance of the class to have their own copies of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should do this:

```
def addplayers(alist):
    players = []
    for item in alist:
        # NOTE reuse the name item is not a good idea here. You can use player instead.
        item = Player("%s" % item)
        players.append(item)
        print "%s has %s HP of life and feels pretty much alive" %  (item.name, item.hitpoints, )
    return players
```

And call it with

```
players = addplayers(playerlist)
print(players[0])
```

The last bit is not about your question but it's better to define your class as

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.lifecondition = True
        self.hitpoints = 100
    def death(self):
        self.lifecondition = False
```

Because you probably want each of your players can have different `hitpoints`. See Python documentation about class variable and instance variable [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Comment: Thank you that actually made me realize what i m missing. basically the return is returning what the loop just did , thus i m able to use it again. print(players[0]).name does the trick indeed. Thank you

Comment: @st00pid If it helped solve your problem, please consider accepting this as answer so it won't appear as unsolved to others.

Comment: Oh thanks for the extra tip about the class as well I may have misunderstood inheritance ^^. Indeed I d like the hitpoints eventually to be different.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address why the original code was not working. This is kind of deep so hang on. In your original code you passed in a list of strings. You created objects based on the strings and you thought you were saving those objects to the list via the item var. That is not what was happening. Each time through the loop the item var was bound to the next string in the list. When you assigned a Player object to item it simply unbinds item from the string and binds it to the Player object leaving the string still in the list.

Comment: @newspire In my original comment under the question, I said " 
You didn't save the item into (possibly) another list. (And use that list later.)". I think that addressed it. I just didn't include that into this answer.

Comment: @Gnijuohz, no criticism of your answer intended. I was just hoping to provide more background. I really had to think about why it wasn't working and found the reason interesting. I guess one way to modify a list in place would be to iterate over the range of list length. Then do the assignment like alist[x]=Player(alist[x]).